# How to increment a typescript variable from Konva.js in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, graphics, konvajs

I included KonvaJS into an Angular 12.x project.

```
    "typescript": "~4.2.x"
    "konva": "^8.1.x",
```

Just like:

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

In the Typescript-Component I bind the stage and add a layer, ..

```js
ngOnInit(): void {

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: width,
  height: height
});
this.stage.add(this.myLayer);

}
```

.. define a box and add some functionality which happens within Konva, just like here (https://konvajs.org/docs/styling/Mouse_Cursor.html).

But I'd like to increment a variable by **click**, hence change a value from inside Konva by triggering a function (or likewise). Therefore I defined a variable ..

```js
  public shapeClicked: string = 'abc';

  constructor() {
    this.myLayer = new Konva.Layer();
    this.shapeClicked = 'cdf';
  }
```

.. and tried to change it, both ..

1. .. Direct ..

```js
    box.on('click', function () {
      this.shapeClicked('yaaay New value');
    });
```

2. .. and Indirect

```js
  box.on('click', this.incrementFoo);
}

incrementFoo() {
  console.log('clicked: ' + this.shapeClicked);
}
```

The Box exists on the layer and the 'click' event is fired.

---

Afterall *this.shapeClicked* remains **undefined** in the 'click'-context although being defined in the constructor (latest).

Is there a valid way to change (global) variables from inside Konva?
Do I have to pass it to Konva somehow?

Obviously .. **console.log('Whatever');** .. and .. **alert('Whatever');** .. do not meet the needed criteria   :-/

Best wishes   :)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use arrow functions to save `this` context:

```js
box.on('click', () => {
  this.shapeClicked = 'box';
});
```